# jstl tags shows unknown tags warning

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl

```
<div id="header">
        <div>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="LoginRegister.jsp">Sample Project</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li <c:if test="${page eq 'login' }"> class="active" </c:if> >
                    <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>LoginRegister.jsp">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li <c:if test="${page eq 'upload' }"> class="active" </c:if> >
                    <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/app/UploadImages.jsp">Upload</a>
                </li>
                <li <c:if test="${page eq 'album' }"> class="active" </c:if> >
                    <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/app/MyAlbum.jsp">My Albums</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="loggedInInfo">
             **<c:if test="${not empty user}">
                <p>Hello ${user}.</p><b><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LogoutServlet">Logout</a></b>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${empty user}">
                <p>You're not logged in!</p>
            </c:if>**
        </div>
</div>
```

In this code am getting  unknown tag warning.I have included jstl jar files in WEB-INF/lib directory.Because highlighted block of code only shows this warning.I can't find my mistake.please help.[image: In this image you can see my error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSTL core tag library is not included in your jspf. Add

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

in your header jspf.